# React Native update state in FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming, expo, mobile-development

I'm building an e commerce app with React Native. I'm stuck with an issue. In the "Basket" Page, I want to show the total price of the items.

I have a state totalPrice set to 0 at the beginning and the when I display each item in a flatlist, i want to update totalPrice (totalPrice = totalPrice + item price * quantity)

My code:

```js
class Basket extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        totalPrice: 0,
      }
    }

  componentDidMount(){

    return fetch(...)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.records,
        }, function(){

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }



    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1}}>

        <ScrollView>

            <FlatList
              data={this.state.dataSource}
              numColumns={1}
              renderItem={({item}) => //displaying the items

              //below i want to update totalPrice but it didn't work
              
              this.setState({
                 totalPrice : this.state.totalPrice + item.quantity * 
                 item.price,
           });  
            }
            />

          </ScrollView>
            
            <View>
            <Text> {this.state.totalPrice} </Text>
            </View>


      </View>

    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use setState inside your component.if you want to get totalPrice you can do same this:

```
    render() {   
    const totalPrice =
    this.state.dataSource &&
     this.state.dataSource.map((item)=> item.quantity).reduce((prev, next) => prev + next)

    return(
    ...
     <Text> {totalPrice} </Text>
    )
}
```

here we use "reduce" ES6 syntax. I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks I found another solution but yours is better

Answer (score 1):

Inside `renderItem` you need to return a component not a function.

your `renderItem` should be something like this

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
 return(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({
             totalPrice : this.state.totalPrice + item.quantity * 
             item.price,
       })}>
       <Text>Your View stays here </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
 />
```

Here I assure you have a data array like this

`[{ quantity: 2, price: 22 }, { quantity: 1, price: 12 }]`
And I see you have wrapped your `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView` for no reason. and it is a good practice to initialise your state first. You can initially set the data or datasource variable to empty array inside your state

`state = {
     data: [],
     ...
   }`